# Rename files with regex incrementing when the same output filename occurs

Tags: bash, unix, rename

I have some files:

```
tridiag_6_a.txt
tridiag_6_b.txt
tridiag_6_c.txt
gauss_6_a.txt
gauss_6_b.txt
```

and I want to get:

```
tridiag1.txt
tridiag2.txt
tridiag3.txt
gauss1.txt
gauss2.txt
```

How can I do this? (Mac OS terminal) I'm stuck on:

```
 $ rename 's/^(.+?)_.*/$1$N.txt/g' *.txt
```

But this increments through all renames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Bash loop:

```
prev_prefix=""
count=1
for file in *.txt; do
  [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
  prefix="${file/_*/}" # get all characters up to the first underscore
  if [[ "$prev_previx" != "$prefix" ]]; then
    count=1
    prev_prefix="$prefix"
  fi
  mv "$file" "$prefix$count".txt
  ((count++))
done
```

Comment: `prev_pefix="$prefix"` in view of `stupid file with space_1.txt`.

Comment: Corrected.  However, I don't think assignments are subject to word splitting and globbing.